# MIPS storing and printing double precision numbers

Tags: assembly, mips

I am trying to get inputs of double precision numbers stored and printed off an array.
According to [here](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/Mars/Help/SyscallHelp.html), to read a double, you use $f0 with code 7
However, I am getting an syntax parse error on this line: `li $f0, 7`

**Edit**: I dont know why, but when Im printing array, it just prints out 0, does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the part of the documentation that says "**Code in $v0**". You load 7 into `$v0` and make your `syscall`, the *result* of which will be put into the `$f0` register.

Comment: Alright, do you know why when Im printing the array, it just prints out 0?

Comment: @Raptrex: You're using `l.d $f0, 0($s2)` to both store the double into the array and read it out. It can do one or the other, but it can't do both.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean. I only see l.d being used once

Comment: @Raptrex: Sorry, the incorrect line is `mov.s    $f12, $f0`. Think very carefully about what `mov.s` does and how that compares to your comment on that line.

Comment: @Gabe doesnt mov.s $f12, $f0 set $f12 = $f0 (the value from my array), where $f12 is the register for printing doubles?

Comment: @Raptrex: What is `mov.s` a mnemonic for? What does it mean in English? How did you know to type in "mov.s"?

Comment: @Gabe Actually, mov.s should be mov.d.  Thank you, this fixed it